# Angular, repopulate select after creating new brand via model form

Tags: angularjs

i am new to the angularJs, I am working on an app, where i have following spec..

- CarController (car create form contains one select for Brands)
- Brand list last option is +Addnew (that open's one model form to create brand associated to the other controller)

Now my question is once Brand is created and model is close, how can I update $scope.brands from carcontroller to update brands list in create new car form?

I will wait for kind replies.

```
 angular.module('application').controller('CarsEditCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, $window,$modal, $state, $stateParams, CarService,BrandService) {
    $scope.getBrands = function () {
        BrandService.getBrands().then(
             function (response) {
$scope.brands = response.data;
     console.log(response.data);
    },
    function (response) { 
     console.log('Error while loading the brands,', response);
    });
    };
$scope.getBrands();
if ($state.includes('cars.edit')) {
  $scope.panelTitle = 'Edit Car';
  $scope.submitButtonTitle = 'Update';
  $scope.getCar($stateParams.guid);
  $scope.update = function () {
    var yearOfProductionDate = new Date($scope.car.yearOfProduction);
    var data = {
     brand: $scope.car.brand.guid, model: $scope.car.model,            yearOfProduction: yearOfProductionDate
};
CarService.updateCar($stateParams.guid, data).then (
    function (response) {
     $scope.showSuccessAlert = true;
     $scope.successAlertMessage = 'Car information is updated successfully.';
    },
    function (response) {
    alert('Error, information is not updated please try again.');
    });};

} else {
    $scope.panelTitle = 'Create New Car';
    $scope.submitButtonTitle = 'Save';
    $scope.create = function() {
     var yearOfProductionDate = new Date($scope.car.yearOfProduction);
     var data = {
     brand: $scope.car.brand.guid, 
     model: $scope.car.model
    };
    CarService.addCar(data).then (
     function (response) {
      $scope.showSuccessAlert = true;
      $scope.successAlertMessage = 'Car information is saved successfully.';
      $window.location = '/#/dashboard/cars/' + response.data.guid;
    },
    function (response) {
     alert(response.data.message);
    });
    };
    }
    $scope.cancel = function () {
     $window.location = '/#/dashboard/cars';
    };
    $scope.closeSuccessAlert = function(index) {
     $scope.showSuccessAlert = false;
    };

   //// MODEL BRAND CREATE FORM     
$scope.openCreateBrandModel = function (open) { 
if (!open) {
    return;
    }
    $scope.car.brand = '';
    $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/pages/dashboard/brands/model-edit-form.html',
    backdrop: false,
    windowClass: 'modal',
    controller: 'BrandsEditCtrl',
    resolve: {
    user: function () {
    return $scope.user;
    }
    }

----Brands Controller---------------------

angular.module('application').controller('BrandsEditCtrl',
    function ($scope,
             $modalInstance,
             $state,
             BrandService) {

    $scope.create = function() {
    var data = {
       name: $scope.brand.name
    };
    BrandService.addBrand(data).then (
     function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.guid);
      $scope.cancel();
    },
    function (response) {
      alert(response.data.message);
    });
    };
    $scope.submit = function () {
     console.log('Submiting user info.');
     /// HERE I NEEED  TO TELL CarsController to update brands list.
     $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
    $scope.cancel = function () {
     $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.brands.push(newBrandYouJustCreated);
```

or you can send an http request to get the fresh brand list, and store it in the scope, just as you probably did initially to have the brands in the scope.

[The documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/modal) explains how to deal with modals:

To know when the dialog has been closed, you need to register a success callback on the modal instance result promise:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open(...);
modalInstance.result.then(function(data) {
    // the modal has been closed, and passed data to its opener
}
```

To pass data to the opener when the modal is closed, from the modal controller, instead of using `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');`, which tells the opener "the user chose to cancel", you rather use

```
$modalInstance.close(theBrandYouHaveJustCreated);
```

which rather tells: "the user didn't chose to cancel. He chose to proceed with the creation of the brand, and here is the brand he created".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But how can i call $scope.brands.push from BrandsController, since  $scope.brands is in CarsController scope.?

Comment: you can use a `service` for that

Comment: I have no idea, because I don't have any idea how you handle your modal dialogs. ui-bootstrap modals have a close() method resolving a promise, that allows communicating back a result to the modal opener when the modal is closed. For help on your code, we need to see your code.

Comment: The relevant code must be in the question itself. Click the edit link at the bottom of the question, and post the code there.

Comment: Sorry I didn't knew that, I have added the code in the post.

Comment: See my edited answer. Also read the documentation carefully. It has an example doing almost exactly what you want to achieve.